# How to replace images from IPA file

Tags: ios, image, replace, ipa, launch-screen

I have build my app and I got the IPA file but I want to change the launch image from the IPA file. I tried to extract the IPA file by remaining it to zip and inside the .app file I changed few images but it seems that those where signed or marked and I can't replace those with new images and apple also rejects the IPA file saying the images are missing. So is there any way to replace those files and not getting this error.?

Comment: change the image within your project using xcode. And build a new IPA file.

Comment: Hey guys thanks you for the reply. @Mr.Tann i am not very friendly with xcode so can you provide me some links to do it.? Also i have seen a video on youtube buy i dont know if that software is available but here is the link : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v0pPeFi3ZMU

Comment: changing image is so easy from ur project and build an ipa file. follow this old video which shows how to add image in your project. link => https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iKuGiJMgMiQ

Comment: Hey, thanks for the link but I used construct 2 and build my app with cocoon so I don't have any xcode project just the IPA file